# Is there a better solution to the code below

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently adding a button that hides and shows rows which are not consecutive. While the below works (to a degree) is there a better option to call the rows than listed below.

```
Sub Button7_Click()

    With Range("5:5, 7:7, 9:9, 11:11, 13:13, 15:15, 17:17, 19:19, 21:21,23:23, 25:25, 27:27, 29:29, 31:31, 33:33, 35:35, 37:37, 39:39, 41:41, 43:43, 45:45, 47:47, 49:49, 51:51, 53:53, 55:55, 63:63, 65:65, 67:67, 69:69, 71:71, 73:73, 75:75, 77:77, 79:79, 81:81, 85:85, 83:83")
        .Select
        .EntireRow.Hidden = Not .EntireRow.Hidden
    End With

End Sub
```

additionally, if I attempt to go beyond the range below I get the error:

> Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed

I'm no expert at excel so as much detail as you can offer in regards to any code changes and implementation would be very much appreciated.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Button7_Click()
For i = 5 to 83 step 2
    Rows(i).entireRow.Hidden = Not Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this has worked a treat. Although it's slow to implement is this normal for macros (I'm a complete novice). many thanks again.

Comment: If you want to speed up your code, adding `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and `Application.EnableEvents = False` (and turning them back on to `true` at the end) will prevent screen redraws that slow a lot of macros down

Answer (score 3):

```
for x=5 to 85 step 2

rows(x).hidden=not rows(x).hidden

next x
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I have implemented the previous post formula. But I really appreciate the reply and help.

Answer (score 0):

You've reached the upper limit string length that can be applied to a range object but there are work-arounds.

Two methods with Union. First with hard-coded construction.

```
Sub Button7_Click()    
    With union(Range("5:5, 7:7, 9:9, 11:11, 13:13, 15:15, 17:17, 19:19, 21:21, 23:23"), _
               range("25:25, 27:27, 29:29, 31:31, 33:33, 35:35, 37:37, 39:39, 41:41"), _
               range("43:43, 45:45, 47:47, 49:49, 51:51, 53:53, 55:55, 63:63, 65:65"), _
               range("67:67, 69:69, 71:71, 73:73, 75:75, 77:77, 79:79, 81:81, 85:85"), _
               range("83:83, 85:85, 87:87, 89:89, 91:91, 93:93, 95:95, 97:97, 99:99"), _
               range("101:101, 103:103, 105:105, 107:107"))
    .EntireRow.Hidden = Not .EntireRow.Hidden
    End With
End Sub
```

Then with optimized loop.

```
Sub Button7_Click()
    dim r as long, rng as range
    set rng = range("5:5, 7:7, 9:9, 11:11, 13:13")
    for r = 10 to 1000 step 10
        set rng =  union(rng, range("5:5, 7:7, 9:9, 11:11, 13:13").offset(r, 0))
    next r
    rng.EntireRow.Hidden = Not rng.EntireRow.Hidden
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

my 0.02 cents

```
Sub Button7_Click()
    Dim rng As Range, i As Long

    Set rng = Range("B1")
    For i = 5 To 83 Step 2
        Set rng = Union(rng, Cells(i, 1))
    Next i
    With Intersect(rng, Columns(1))
        .EntireRow.Hidden = Not .EntireRow.Hidden
    End With
End Sub
```